# Field within structure take random values

Tags: c, structure

I'm new to C and I'm trying to define a matrix using a struct and some methods that will change the int** field of the struct. The matrix is supposed to be dynamically allocated and also resizable in how many rows it can have. When I run the program below and print out the values of the matrix in main, the matrix just have random values, not the ones inserted in genMatrix() and addRow(). What am I doing wrong? Very grateful for any help.

I define the struct like this:

```
typedef struct matrix {
    int** matrix;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int capacity;
} matrix;
```

And then have the following methods that should change the field of the struct:

```
matrix* genMatrix() {
    matrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix));

    initMatrix(matrix, 100, 3, 200);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int row[] = {i+j, i*j, i-j};            
            addRow(matrix, row);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}   

void initMatrix(matrix* matrix, int rows, int cols, int capacity) {
    matrix->matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix->matrix[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }
    matrix->cols = cols;
    matrix->rows = rows;
    matrix->capacity = capacity;
}

void addRow(matrix* matrix, int* row) {
    if (matrix->rows == matrix->capacity) {
        matrix->capacity *= 2;
        matrix->matrix = realloc(matrix->matrix, matrix->capacity * sizeof(int*));
    }

    matrix->matrix[matrix->rows++] = row;
}
```

And in main I call the function genMatrix and then print the result out, but get random values like 32691, -1240670624 etc.

```
int main() {
    matrix* matrix = genMatrix();   
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly print? Do you print the pointer to the struct?

Comment: at initMatrix `malloc(rows * sizeof(int*))` -> `malloc(capacity * sizeof(int*))`

Comment: Yeah, good point BLUEPIXY. I'm doing the allocation wrong, I don't use the capacity variable. Thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHen you try to add a row here:

```
        int row[] = {i+j, i*j, i-j};            
        addRow(matrix, row);
```

the data you are adding is a temporary local variable. On the next loop iteration it will get overwritten and then when the loop exits it will go out of scope.

You need to *allocate* some memory for the new row data, e.g. using `malloc`:

```
        int * row = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
        row[0] = i+j;       
        row[1] = i*j;       
        row[2] = i-j;       
        addRow(matrix, row);
```

Don't forget to `free` all these row allocations later when you're done with the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Good that you added an example!

Comment: Could you also by any chance take a look at if I'm doing the reallocation of new rows correctly when the it has reached the maximum number of rows? Thanks

Comment: It looks OK but you need to be aware that realloc can fail, so with your current code you would (a) not detect the failure and (b) you would leak memory even if you did detect the failure. You should assign the result of realloc to a temporary pointer, check this for NULL, then handle the error if it fails, otherwise assign the temporary pointer to matrix->matrix only if realloc succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `row`, a local variable. This pointer ceases to be valid once its scope ends:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    int row[] = {i+j, i*j, i-j};            
    addRow(matrix, row);
}
```

You must dynamically allocate memory for the row data, too.

Answer (score 0):

row is a local variable.As soon as loop goes for new iteration data gets overwritten and after loop exits data goes out of scope .
So use 
int * row = malloc(NumOfRows * sizeof(int)); 
and then row members.